# TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not NoneType

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am trying to create a simple scraper to gatherbasketball stats. I was able to get the info I want, however, I can't figure out how to organized it all in a table.

I keep getting a "TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not NoneType."

Please see my code below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import re

url = 'https://basketball.realgm.com/ncaa/boxscore/2021-01-29/North-Texas-at-Rice/367436'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content , 'html.parser')

#Extracting Columns
tables = soup.find('div', class_= 'boxscore-gamesummary')
columns = tables.find_all('th', class_='nosort')

#Extracting Stats
tables = soup.find('div', class_= 'boxscore-gamesummary')
stats = tables.find_all('td')

#Filling DataFrame
temp_df = pd.DataFrame(stats).transpose()
temp_df.columns = columns

final_df = pd.concat([final_df,temp_df], ignore_index=True)

final_df
```

Looking forward to hearing from someone

Comment: Please post the complete error message including back trace.

Comment: You might want to also go through your code again to make sure each section is giving you the outputs you expect/want

Answer (score 1):

Pandas already has a built-in method to get a dataframe from HTML which should make things way easier here.

**Code**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://basketball.realgm.com/ncaa/boxscore/2021-01-29/North-Texas-at-Rice/367436'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content , 'html.parser')

tables = soup.find('div', class_= 'boxscore-gamesummary').find_all('table')
df = pd.read_html(str(tables))[0]

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
  Unnamed: 0   1   2  Final
0  UNT (8-5)  36  43     79
1  RU (10-7)  37  37     74
```